# Возможно ли связать, средствами HTML + CSS, исполнение нескольких действий при наведении на div элемент?

Tags: html, css

Хотелось бы сделать выдвижной блок при наведении на навигационное меню сайта, при это должен появляться одновременно border-bottom и происходить разворот стрелки.
Трансформацию отдельных элементов я сделал, но не получается связать их.
Воссоздаю для себя пример этого сайта: https://www.paypal.com/ru/.

```css
*
{
background-color: black;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu_list
{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
list-style: none;
}

.section
{
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.arrow
{
border: solid white;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
height: 4px;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 4px;
width: 4px;
}

.down
{
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.down:hover
{
transform: rotate(-135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.dropdown_list
{
display: none;
}

.border_bottom
{
border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
transition: all 0.3s;
}

.border_bottom:hover
{
border-bottom: solid white 2px;
}

.wrap
{
display: flex;
padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="border_bottom">
   <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://www.paypal.com/ru/webapps/mpp/home" class="section">Личный</a>
    <div class="arrow down"></div>
    <div class="dropdown_list">
  <ul>
   <li> Как работает PayPal. Возможности Личного счета</li>
   <li> Оплачивайте онлайн. Онлайн-платежи по всему миру</li>
   <li> Отправляйте переводы. Переводы по России и за границу</li>
   <li> Получайте переводы. Запросите платеж у любого пользователя</li>
   <li> Скачайте приложение PayPal. Управляйте счетом с мобильного</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Упорсти и сделай сниппет в вопросе - [mcve]. Ответ да, но не факт, что при твоей разметке.

Comment: Да, разметку придется чуть изменить, и можно сделать без проблем

Comment: На чистом CSS изменить стиль родителя при наведении на дочерний элемент не получится, а у вас там нужно при наведении на навигационное меню менять задний фон на градиент у всей шапки. Как уже написали, тут нужно либо менять разметку, если это поможет, либо через JS.

Comment: Извините друзья за кривую разметку. Всё вроде бы ок, когда начинаешь собирать, но перевалив через определенное количество ставок - здесь вот начинается путаница.
Видимо надо записывать конструктор прежде всего на листе бумаги (полный html, до css).

Пример частично отредактировал.

Спасибо за замечания.

Может быть увеличить область каждого элемента в контейнере и задать им абсолютное позиционирование (или это бред?), дабы они не смещали друг друга, но при наведении курсора на весь контейнер задействовались функции элементов?

Comment: На одном css это вряд ли можно сделать так, чтобы код вообще был читабельным, а про семантическую разметку можно и подавно забыть.

Comment: максимум на что у меня хватило терпения https://jsfiddle.net/y3f970je/